# Manifold problems

Tags: modeling

I am doing a model to 3d print, I finished it, but when I put it on the slicing program, the model shows all sorts of bugs.

After a search, I found that this is a Manifold problem, and then I made my way into the 3d Print Toolbox in Blender, but after I click the "Make Manifold" in the Clean Up section, almost the entire model disappears.

How can I fix it?

Heres the model:
https://mega.nz/file/ps5VVY7a#hE5nJfmL2FNVv0XUvkA4b8wY9mN78vFlhAtcA7HVnjY

Answer (score 2):

Select your object. Go into Edit Mode. Select everything. Press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose By Loose Parts.

You will see that your model is made up of five separate meshes, and that would be problematic to print.

Two of these meshes seem to be floating around and not part of anything; it seems safe to delete them.

The other two are cubes in the dashboard area. If you need them, i think you need to manually make them part of the main mesh by deleting geometry around the cubes and connect the cubes to the rest using <kbd>F</kbd>. You'll want to be careful not to create non-manifold geometry while doing this. For example, when you are done each cube should have 5 faces, and not 6 where one face is hidden on the inside.

This might also help:
[What is non-manifold geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry?rq=1)

I'm not sure but I suspect you might run into more problems trying to print this model, but i guess you can start by solving this issue. In any case, good luck.

**EDIT:**

As I suspected your model had a lot of issues that needed to be resolved before it can be 3D printed. I've looked a bit closer and for instance, next to the gear stick there are a lot of faces sticking into the floor. It makes me wonder how this model was created, and if it were possible to resolve these issues at that first step.

In any case, Select Non Manifold might help if you want to visualize and learn about the issues of this model, or any other model for that mater.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: Yeah... I can't fix it

Comment: I was afraid of that. That's to bad. I edited my answer; hope it helps a little bit.

Comment: I found my way into that option yesterday, but I have no Idea how to proceed from there.

Comment: I think the model has a lot of problems, and i think it will take a lot of time and some skill to solve them all. If i had this problem i would look into getting a better model to begin with. And if that wasn't an option, i would (because i have some 3D drawing experience) re-draw it from scratch sacrificing a lot of detail, and maybe copy and integrate some parts into the new model. I'm afraid there isn't an easy fix for this model as it is now. In any case, if you do any further work on this project, i wish you good luck with it.